# $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}\ dx$, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

I have the following 3 improper integrals to see if they diverge or converge, I'd like some opinions to see if my proofs are right, and a help in the last one

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}\ dx$$$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}\ dx$$

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x}{1-e^x} \ dx$$

a) $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}} \ dx$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx =  \int_0^{\infty} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ dx  = 2x^{\frac{1}{2}}|_0^{\infty} = \infty$$

Since $(1+x)\sqrt{x}>\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} = x^2$

because $1+x>\sqrt{x}$ for $x\ge 0$, then

$$\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}} < \frac{1}{x^2}$$

and then

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}} \ dx< \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$$

b) $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}} \ dx $$

$$\sqrt{x^6+1}>\sqrt{x^4} = x^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}<\frac{1}{x^2}$$

therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}} \ dx = 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}} \ dx< 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$$

it's enough to see if

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^6+1} \ dx$$

converges.

Since, for $0\le x \le 1$, we have $x^6+1>x^6$, then

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^6+1} \ dx<\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^6} \ dx= -\frac{1}{5}x^{-5}|_0^1 = -\frac{1}{5}$ and therefore the original integral converges

c)

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x}{1-e^x} \ dx = \frac{1}{1-e^x}\frac{x^2}{2}|_1^{\infty}-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{2}(-1)\frac{1}{(1-e^x)^2}e^x$$

As you can see, integration by parts won't help.  I also couldn't find a comparison, because I don't even know if this integral converges or diverges, could somebody help me?

Comment: I think there is a typo in $$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{6} + 1}} dx = 2 \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{6} + 1}} dx$$ The second integral should have lower bound $0$ due to the evenness of the integrand, not $1$. Either that or you neglected the integral over $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Mattos You're right, I corrected

Comment: Note that you can evaluate the first integral exactly by making the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$: $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{1+u^2}=2\lim_{a\to\infty}\tan^{-1}a=\pi\;.$$

Comment: Also, what do you means when you say "it's enough to see if $\int^1_0 (x^6+1)^{-1}\ dx$ converges".

Comment: @JackyChong because the part from $1$ to $\infty$ converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point  $c$ $$I=\int \limits^{\infty }_{1}\frac{x}{1-e^{x}} dx=\overbrace{\int \limits^{\infty }_{0}\frac{x}{1-e^{x}} dx} \limits^{I_{1}}-\overbrace{\int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{x}{1-e^{x}} dx} \limits^{I_{2}}$$
 $$ I_{1}=\boxed {\frac{-\pi ^{2}}{6}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \     \  \  \ \Rightarrow(1) $$
$$I_{2}=- \int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} dx=\int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{\text{ln}\left( y+1\right) }{y\left( y+1\right) } dy \ \     \ \ \Rightarrow(2)=\overbrace{\int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{\text{ln}\left( y+1\right) }{y} dy} \limits^{I_{3}}-\overbrace{\int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{\text{ln}\left( y+1\right) }{y+1} dy} \limits^{I_{4} } $$
$$ I_{4}=\frac{\text{ln}^{2}\left( y+1\right) }{2} ^{1}_{0}=\left( -\frac{\text{ln}^{2}\left( e^{x}\right) }{2} \right) ^{1}_{0}= \boxed {\frac{-1}{2} }$$
$$ I_{3}=\int \limits^{1}_{0}\frac{\text{ln}\left( y+1\right) }{y} dy=\int \limits^{-1}_{0}\frac{-\text{ln}\left( 1-z\right) }{-z} dy \     \   \ \Rightarrow  (3) 
 =-\text{li}_{2}\left( z\right) ^{-1}_{0}=-\text{li}_{2}\left( -y\right) ^{1}_{0}=-\text{li}_{2}\left( 1-e^{x}\right) ^{1}_{0}=\boxed{-\text{li}_{2}\left( 1-e\right)}  $$ 
Therefore

> > $$ I=\color{fuchsia}{\boxed{\frac{-\pi ^{2}}{6} -\frac{1}{2} -\text{li}_{2}\left( 1-e\right)}} $$

---

## Explanation

- (1) use [Ramanujan Master theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html)
- (2) use substitution  $e^{x}-1=y$
- (3) use substitution $y=-z $

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
&\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{x}} \leq \int^1_0 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}+\int^\infty_1 \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}<\infty\\
& \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^6}} \leq \int^1_{-1} dx + 2\int^\infty_{1} \frac{dx}{x^3}<\infty\\
& \left|\int^\infty_1 \frac{x}{1-e^x}\ dx \right|\leq \int^\infty_1 \frac{x}{|1-e^x|}dx = \int^\infty_1 \frac{x}{e^x-1}\ dx \leq 2\int^\infty_1 xe^{-x}\ dx <\infty.
\end{align}
Note: for the last one I use the fact that $e^x-1\geq e^x-\frac{1}{2}e^x$.

Comment: Very concise compared to what I was preparing to post.  +1

Comment: but did you see anything wrong with mine proof?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x} \neq x^2$

Comment: do you see a problem in my second integral solution?